# git pull using different SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to pull changes into a repo. The repo's origin was originally located on a different git server, now the origin has moved to another server. On the new server we have a generic user called 'app', on other machines we have added the app user private key and a config file like so:

```
# in /root/.ssh/config
Host gitlab-app
  HostName git.ist
  User git
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_app
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and could use a command like this to clone the repo:

```
git clone gitlab-app:software-development/my_repo.git
```

Which works. The problem is that on the particular server im talking about the repo had already been cloned from the previous location. I've changed the remote url of the repo to the new location but when trying to pull over ssh I am asked for a password. I guess because there is no key from this server on the gitlab host. Hence the generic 'app' user.

My question is, how do I configure my repo to use the app user key for ssh when I am running the pull command as root user?

In some other threads I saw this:

```
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_app -F /dev/null'
```

But it had no effect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was a simple solution. When I changed the remote-url of the repo on the server I just copied and pasted the standard url from the gitlab page. What I needed to change it to was:

from

```
git@git.ist:software-development/my_repo.git
```

to

```
gitlab-app:software-development/my_repo.git
```

So that the git config file is actually used. Just like in the clone link.

So basically:

```
git remote set-url origin gitlab-app:software-development/my_repo.git
```